# Align ActionBar Title to center Xamarin

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, android-actionbar, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms, i removed my icon, now I want to put the Action Bar Title at center, actually it's on left.

I saw some pages saying  to I use `getSupportActionBar()` but this is not found on my visual studio, I'm trying to remove it on my Style.xml or on my MainActivity.

[image]

MainActivity.XML

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace App5.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "App5", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/CustomActionBarTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {        
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);            
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            ActionBar.SetIcon(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }

    }
}
```

Style.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
         parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

  </style>
  <!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar"
         parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
  <item name="android:background">#000000</item>

  </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with `Xamarin`, the only way is programatically:

```
LinearLayout lLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
lLayout .SetGravity(GravityFlags.CenterVertical);
lLayout .LayoutParams textViewParameters = 
                        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
textViewParameters.RightMargin = (int)(30 * activity.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

TextView myTitle = new TextView(activity);        
myTitle.Text = text;
myTitle.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
lLayout.AddView(myTitle ,textViewParameters);

ActionBar.LayoutParams actionbarParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ActionBar.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
activity.ActionBar.SetCustomView(lLayout, actionbarParams);
```

Comment: On 'new LinearLayout(activity);" I dont have an activity created, I'm using the MainActivity as I sent on my code above, so how can I define the activity on my MainActivity ? I'm working with MasterDetailPage

Comment: Hi Fred,  var activity = Activity;

Comment: "CS0119 'Activity' is a type, which is not valid in the given context " error caused when used: var activity = Activity;

Comment: I used 'Activity activity = new Activity(); but now the error is: "CS0118 'lLayout' is a variable but is used like a type"

Comment: NO!, don´t create a new instance, use current instance of Activity.

Comment: All I tried is going wrong, var activity = Activity give this error: " 
"CS0119 'Activity' is a type, which is not valid in the given context " and "   lLayout.LayoutParameters textViewParameters" give this error:"CS0118 'lLayout' is a variable but is used like a type"

Comment: @Jorgesys : Did you finally fix the issue? Any chance there is a clear solution.

Comment: the example is not compiling and misleading to new programmers starting with xamarin "new LinearLayout(activity);" activity need to be "this" for example